# Primefaces selectOneMenu itemDisabled inside composite component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, composite-component, selectonemenu

we created a composite component containing a primefacs selectOneMenu and some markup around it. Now we've a new requirement to make some of the items disabled. How can this be done inside a composite component? What we tried was:

Composite Component:

```
<composite:interface>
    ...
    <composite:attribute name="itemDisabled" method-signature="java.lang.Boolean itemDisabled(javax.faces.model.SelectItem)" />
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    ...
    <p:selectOneMenu id="#{cc.attrs.name}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.selectedItems}"
            var="item"
            itemDisabled="#{cc.attrs.itemDisabled}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    ...
</composite:implementation>
```

View:

```
<ctags:input_selectOneMenu name="foo"
    selectedItems="#{bean.selectItems}"
    itemDisabled="#{bean.itemDisabled(item)}" />
```

Bean:

```
public boolean itemDisabled(javax.faces.model.SelectItem item) {
    return true;
}
public List<javax.faces.model.SelectItem> getSelectItems() {
    return list of selectitems...
}
```

A breakpoint in the itemDisabled method is never hit and all the items are enabled.

Thanks, kopi

Comment: check this out : `<f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.selectedItems}"
            var="item"itemDisabled="#{cc.attrs.itemDisabled(item)}" />`

Comment: This leads to a javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException. itemDisabled="#{cc.attrs.itemDisabled(item)}" Illegal attempt to pass arguments to a composite component lookup expression (i.e. cc.attrs.[identifier]).

Comment: You seem to be passing a value (item) in the ctags `itemDisabled` attribute that is only available IN the ocmposite. That is not going to work afaik

Comment: I removed the item param in the view before testing it. Now I've <ctags:input_selectOneMenu name="foo"
    selectedItems="#{bean.selectItems}"
    itemDisabled="#{bean.itemDisabled}" /> which leads to the exception mentioned above.